# Angular Typescript - Property 'files' does not exist on type 'string | { ... }'

Tags: arrays, angular, typescript, string, properties

I'm starting on Angular and Typescript and I'm currently stumbling on a problem, so I'm looking for some guidance. Indeed, I would like to create something like this:

[Structure Mockup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtaKT.jpg)

But I'm getting the follow error in my IDE saying:

```
Property 'files' does not exist on type 'string | { id: string; name: string; img: string; videos: number[]; files: number[]; }'
```

However, my console.log are well displaying so I don’t understand

Here is a summary of my code:

```
public meal = [
    {
        id : "0",
        title:"Ingredients",
        ingredients: [
            {id:"0", name:"Lorem ipsum", img:"assets/loremipsum.png", videos:["0"], files:["0","1"]},
            {id:"1", name:"Lorem ipsum", img:"assets/loremipsum.png", videos:["1"], files:["0"]},
            {id:"2", name:"Lorem ipsum", img:"assets/loremipsum.png", videos:["0", "2"], files:["1"]},
            {id:"3", name:"Lorem ipsum", img:"assets/loremipsum.png", videos:["1", "2"], files:["0"]}
        ],
        videos:[
            {id:"0", url:"loremipsum"},
            {id:"1", url:"loremipsum"},
            {id:"2", url:"loremipsum"}
        ],
        files:[
            {id:"0", title:"Lorem ipsum", link:"assets/loremipsum.pdf"},
            {id:"1", title:"Lorem ipsum", link:"assets/loremipsum.pdf"}
        ],
        questions:[
            {id:"0", question:"Lorem ipsum ?", answer:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"},
            {id:"1", question:"Lorem ipsum ?", answer:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"},
            {id:"2", question:"Lorem ipsum ?", answer:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"}
        ]
    },
    {
        id : "1",
        title:"Restaurants",
        ingredients:[],
        videos:[
            {id:"0", url:"loremipsum"}
        ],
        files:[
            {id:"0", title:"Lorem ipsum", link:"assets/loremipsum.pdf"},
            {id:"1", title:"Lorem ipsum", link:"assets/loremipsum.pdf"}
        ],
        questions:[
            {id:"0", question:"Lorem ipsum ?", answer:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"},
            {id:"1", question:"Lorem ipsum ?", answer:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"}
        ]
    },
    {
        id : "2",
        title:"Equipment",
        ingredients:[],
        videos:[],
        files:[
            {id:"0", title:"Lorem ipsum", link:"assets/loremipsum.pdf"},
            {id:"1", title:"Lorem ipsum", link:"assets/loremipsum.pdf"}
        ],
        questions:[
            {id:"0", question:"Lorem ipsum ?", answer:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"},
            {id:"1", question:"Lorem ipsum ?", answer:"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit"}
        ]
    }
]



ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getRouteParams();
}


getRouteParams() {
    this.routeSub = this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        if(params['id']){
            this.mealId = params['id'];
        }
        else{
            this.mealId = "0";
        }
        this.IngredientFiles();
    });
    this.routeSubFragment = this.activatedRoute.fragment.subscribe(fragments => {
        if(fragments){
            this.ingredientId = fragments;
        }
        else{
            this.ingredientId = "0";
        }
        this.IngredientFiles();
    });
}


IngredientFiles() {
    let filesDisplayed = [];
    if(this.meal[this.mealId].ingredients.length > 0){
        for(let mealFile of this.meal[this.mealId].files){
            console.log("mealFile: "+mealFile.id) // WORKS
            if(this.meal[this.mealId].ingredients[this.ingredientId].files.length > 0){
                for(let ingredientFile of this.meal[this.mealId].ingredients[this.ingredientId].files){
                    if (ingredientFile == mealFile.id){
                        console.log("ingredientFile: "+ingredientFile) // WORKS
                        filesDisplayed.push(ingredientFile)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you in advance for helping

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line "Property 'files' does not exist on type 'string | { id: string; name: string; img: string; videos: number[]; files: number[]; }'" means that TypeScript is trying to guess the typing of `meal` based on its value. The error comes from it not guessing quite right. And `console.log` shows a value, because the value is actually there.

Not declaring type for complex structures like this is generally a bad idea (think about yourself a few weeks for now, trying to recall "what is supposed to go into a meal?"). You can use sth like

```
type Ingredient = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  img: string;
  videos: string[];
  files: string;
}

type Video = // definition here
// the rest of the definition

type Meal = {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  ingredients: Ingredient[];
  videos: Video[];
  files: FileEntry[]; // `File` is reserved 
  questions: Question[];
}

//... 

meal: Meal[] = { // actual value here
```